# Shoulda rspec matchers ensure_inclusion_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, shoulda

I have a test using shoulda that is failing for reasons I don't understand. Any idea what the fix is for this? I hardcoded the array for testing purposes.

All my other shoulda matcher based tests are working fine.

Validation

```
validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => ["Active", "Closed"]
```

Test:

```
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:status).in_array(["Active", "Closed"]) }
```

Failure

```
Failure/Error: it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:status).in_array(["Active", "Closed"]) }
   ["Active", "Closed"] doesn't match array in validation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code for that matcher:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/ensure_inclusion_of_matcher.rb#L88

Do you have another validation which prevents nil or blank values for `:status`?

Comment: Thanks. That looks like the issue.

Comment: the code has changed, the new link is: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/ensure_inclusion_of_matcher.rb#L22

Comment: Link changed again: https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/shoulda-matchers/2.2.0/files/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/ensure_inclusion_of_matcher.rb